# Which among best stochastic optimizers gives better visualization?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, deep-learning

I am trying to make a visual comparison of predictions among the best neural network optimization algorithms [1] implemented from scratch.

- The loss for **SGD with momentum** is: 0.2235
- The loss for **RMSprop** is: 0.2075
- The loss for **Adam** is: 0.6931

  Are the results for **Adam** correct or not?

Here is what I have got as graphs:
[image: SGD Comparison graphs]

- Code for **SGD with momentum**:

```py
np.random.seed(42)

w = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
eta = 0.05 # learning rate
alpha = 0.9 # momentum
nu = np.zeros_like(w)

n_iter = 100
batch_size = 4
loss = np.zeros(n_iter)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))

for i in range(n_iter):
    ind = np.random.choice(X_expanded.shape[0], batch_size)
    loss[i] = compute_loss(X_expanded, y, w)
    if i % 10 == 0:
        visualize(X_expanded[ind, :], y[ind], w, loss)

    grad = compute_grad(X_expanded, y, w)
    nu = alpha * nu + eta * grad
    w = w - nu

visualize(X, y, w, loss)
plt.clf()
```

- Code for **RMSprop**:

```py
np.random.seed(42)

w = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.])
eta = 0.1 # learning rate
alpha = 0.9 # moving average of gradient norm squared
g2 = np.zeros_like(w)
eps = 1e-8

n_iter = 100
batch_size = 4
loss = np.zeros(n_iter)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
for i in range(n_iter):
    ind = np.random.choice(X_expanded.shape[0], batch_size)
    loss[i] = compute_loss(X_expanded, y, w)
    if i % 10 == 0:
        visualize(X_expanded[ind, :], y[ind], w, loss)

    grad = compute_grad(X_expanded, y, w)
    grad2 = grad ** 2
    g2 = alpha * g2 + (1-alpha) * grad2
    w = w - eta * grad / np.sqrt(g2 + eps)
    
visualize(X, y, w, loss)
plt.clf()
```

- Code for **Adam**:

```py
np.random.seed(42)
w = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.])

eta = 0.01 # learning rate
beta1 =  0.9 # moving average of gradient norm
beta2 = 0.999 # moving average of gradient norm squared
m = np.zeros_like(w) # Initial 1st moment estimates
nu = np.zeros_like(w) # Initial 2nd moment estimates
eps = 1e-8 # A small constant for numerical stability

n_iter = 100
batch_size = 4
loss = np.zeros(n_iter)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
for i in range(n_iter):
    ind = np.random.choice(X_expanded.shape[0], batch_size)
    loss[i] = compute_loss(X_expanded, y, w)
    if i % 10 == 0:
        visualize(X_expanded[ind, :], y[ind], w, loss)

    grad = compute_grad(X_expanded, y, w)
    grad2 = grad ** 2

    m = ((beta1 * m) + ((1 - beta1) * grad)) / (1 - beta1)
    nu = ((beta2 * nu) + ((1 - beta2) * grad2)) / (1 - beta2)
    w = (w - eta * m) / (np.sqrt(nu) + eps)

visualize(X, y, w, loss)
plt.clf()
```

I am expecting to get a lower cost for Adam. I mean less than that provided by RMSprop (0.2075).

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/37723962/10543310

Comment: Try to make lr less.

Comment: or try to compare your algorithms with someting like tensorflow